# How to pull configuration options out of method body and use configuration class in Dot Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core-3.1

noob here. I have followed the QuickStarts for IdentityServer 4. I am at the point of cleaning up code. I am using Net Core 3.1. My Startup.ConfigureServices has become crowded and I wanted to clean it up and put the configuration options, value(s) into a class - in the same way that IdentityServer 4 uses a class for the IdentityResources, ApiScopes, ApiResources and Client configuration options.

I have read many blog posts and I see from, https://andrewlock.net/avoiding-startup-service-injection-in-asp-net-core-3/ how to add configuration to the IoC container for custom services, but I haven't found a way to pull out the options/values for framework services such as Identity Core, or `services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect()` for example.

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
      options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
      options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
    {
      options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/denied";
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        /***  HOW DO I PUT THE BELOW KEY/VALUES INTO A CONFIG CLASS  ***/

        options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io";
        options.ClientId = "server.hybrid";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
 
        options.SaveTokens = true;
                    
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name", 
            RoleClaimType = "role"
        };
    });
```

And use that config class like this

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources) <-- From the Config class
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes) <-- From the Config class
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients); <-- From the Config class
```

So in case my question wasn't clear, how can I make a Config class and pass that class into `.AddOpenIdConnect(MyConfigClass)` to clean up the ConfigureServices method (IoC Container?)

Is the above code the best/cleanest way to configure services in the IoC Container? Is the answer I am looking for in Andrew Lock's blog post and I just didn't understand it? I am making the assumption that I can pass a class into the .AddOpenIdConnect extension method in the same way that I can with IS4 .AddInMemoryIdentityResources

Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Microsoft services follow the same [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Firstly, you could move those lambda methods to static methods, perhaps on different classes. Which seems to be what your `Config` example has done. You just need to make sure your static methods have the same function signature.

For example, `.AddAuthentication` takes an `Action<AuthenticationOptions>` delegate as an argument. So any `static void foo(AuthenticationOptions o)` method could be passed in instead.

Or you could write services that implement `IConfigureOptions<T>` and register those. This is particularly useful if you need to access other services, like a database for example, in order to configure those options types.

Comment: Thx Dude. As it turns out I went with Jeremy's answer though I needed to to use a param type of OpenIdConnectOptions rather then AuthenticationOptions (for the .AddOpenIdConnect extension method). For the .AddAuthentication extension method, Jeremy's answer was spot on.